# Get all text field value located in a specific class

Tags: jquery

I want to get all fields that are located in a single class name, for example my code like.

```
<div class="test">
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
</div>

<div class="test">
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
 <input type="text" class="text-field" />
</div>
```

I want to get the `each loop` in which it return me the text fields value that is located in this class. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".test .text-field")
```

**EDIT:**

To get values try this:

```
$(".test .text-field").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: i want all of the values of every text fields.

Comment: If anyone wants to get the value of NON-input elements, use `.html()` rather than `.val()`

Answer (score 45):

If you want all the values into an array, you can do this:

```
var texts= $(".test .text-field").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: awesome very nice and beautiful and clean and ... and

Answer (score 4):

Here's another method to obtain an **array of the input values**:

```
Array.from($('.test .text-field').get(), e => e.value)
```

Or alternatively:

```
[].map.call($('.test .text-field').get(), e => e.value)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$(".test input[type=\"text\"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

From cwallenpoole's answer following  should work

```
$.each( $(".test input[type=\"text\"]"), function(index, ele){
   alert( ele.val());
 });
```