# how get all values of one class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

I am trying to get all values of a class input fields. but it is return only one fields value

Html code

```
<div id="mydiv">
<input class="seconds" type="text" value="40">
<input class="seconds" type="text" value="20">
<span class="countdown"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/vendor/jquery-3.1.0.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.missofis-countdown.js') }}"></script>


<script>

var ek=$('.seconds').val();

console.log(ek);
$( '.countdown' ).countdown( {
  from: ek, // 3 minutes (3*60)
  to: 0, // stop at zero
  movingUnit: 1000, // 1000 for 1 second increment/decrements
  timerEnd: undefined,
  outputPattern: '$day Day $hour : $minute : $second',
  autostart: true,
});
</script>
```

I want to get values of both input fields having same class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all text field value located in a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758301/get-all-text-field-value-located-in-a-specific-class)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to create array of the values

```js
var ek = $('.seconds').map((_,el) => el.value).get()

console.log(ek)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
<input class="seconds" type="text" value="40">
<input class="seconds" type="text" value="20">
<span class="countdown"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you run this script. script supposed to run countdown for both inputs

Comment: Not without a better understanding of what is expected or a link to the countdown docs. Your question was only how to get both values from the inputs nd that's what the answer does

Comment: yeah you are right but was one part.
let me explain you. code is getting values from two input fields having same class.
first step wan to get values from those input fields which  is done.
now second step is convert these values into countdown and display in span tag having  ` countdown` class

Comment: here is plugin docs

https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Multipurpose-jQuery-Counter-Timer-Plugin-Missofis.html

Comment: So you want `from` and `to` values? They would be `+ek[0]` and `+ek[1]`

Comment: i did this but it is giving NaN
`
var ek=[];
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
$('.seconds').each(function() { ek.push($(this).val()); });
console.log(ek[i]);

$( '.countdown' ).each(function(i) {     
$(this).countdown(
    
      { from: ek[i], // 3 minutes (3*60) 
to: 0, // stop at zero
 movingUnit: 1000, // 1000 for 1 second increment/decrements
 timerEnd: undefined, 
outputPattern: '$day Day $hour : $minute : $second',
 autostart: true, });
    });
}
`

Comment: Probably need to convert string values to numbers

Comment: I was missing '+'

Answer (score 1):

Attribute methods will only ever get the value of the first element.

To get multiple you have to iterate( loop ) over every element returned by the selector.

```
var ek=[];
$('.seconds').each(function() { ek.push($(this).val()); });
console.log(ek);
```

Timers:

**Make sure you add as many countdown spans as you want timers in your html.**

```
$( '.countdown' ).each(function(index) { 
$(this).countdown( { from: ek[index], // 
3 minutes (3*60) 
to: 0, // stop at zero
 movingUnit: 1000, // 1000 for 1 second increment/decrements
 timerEnd: undefined, 
outputPattern: '$day Day $hour : $minute : $second',
 autostart: true, });
    });
```

**Note**: I apologize for formatting. I'm on mobile.

Comment: it works now can you please tell me how i can var ek in countdown method from: ek ?

Comment: @BILALARSHADMUHAMMADARSHAD well,  you have one countdown span. Likely it's just going to overwrite it. Add as many countdown spans as seconds inputs

Comment: it is giving NaN.. is it because of one countdown span?

Comment: @BILALARSHADMUHAMMADARSHAD I gotta be honest,  I can't troubleshoot this for you right now. I'm on mobile and testing is really,  really difficult this way. If you can't figure it out I'll take a look back at this later, but if it's showing NaN my guess would be that the inputs don't have the correct values when the code is attempted. You probably need to set countdown to run AFTER the inputs have values.

Answer (score 0):

A more simplistic approach is:

```
$('.loadedDate').map(function(){return this.value;}).get()
```